# RAID 5 setup not being noticed with Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, raid5, dell-perc

I have just received a new DELL PowerEdge R310 Server and according to my job I need to set up all 4 500GB drives to run using the RAID 5 configuration. When I go into the controller configuration screen and set the drives up and the configuration I move onto the Windows Server 2008 R2 installation. My issue is that Windows does not detect the RAID configuration at all. I am trying to install the OS from a USB drive and the server has a PERC S300 RAID Controller. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the OS using Dell installation CD (System Buid and Update Utility). You boot from the CD provided, it asks you for the configuration, preloads the drivers, and the asks you to insert the OS CD. If you have trouble with you, you can call Dell support, they can guide you through it

Comment: I had to do this part with 2 USB sticks, but in the end it finally worked out nicely. Whatever happened to the days when Dell supplied you with everything you need instead of finding out that we have to go online to download different files.

Comment: You should specifically ask for media now. Dell has been receiving many complaints, that when someone orders hundreds of systems, they get too much media, and if you're conscious of it, it's hard to recycle so many CDs. So they changed the policy now, and everything is available via http download, but to get media you have to specify a request. Check the online order forms - it's all there

Answer (score 0):

Erm...install from a USB drive? did that come with the server? where did you get it? if it's not a Dell supplied one then did you download the drivers from Dell? I suspect that's all the problem is.

Comment: Our server did not come with a DVD drive nor do we have an external one for use in the office. I preloaded the USB with the OS DVD that came with the Server.

Comment: Ah I see, that DVD should have come with the right drivers pre-installed then, I was worried in case you're put a regular retail copy of the code on the USB which may not have had the drivers but it looks like that's covered. Have you got something like a 'live' Ubuntu CD (or USB in this case)? you could see if it spots the controller; basically it's probably either a broken/semi-broken controller or driver issue - probably the latter.